# Custom Card Shape Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have developed an app with GridView on Flutter. GridView items are Card and the default card shape is Rectangle with a radius of 4.

I know there is shape property for Card Widget and it takes ShapeBorder class but I am unable to find how to use ShapeBorder class and customize my cards in GridView.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 326):

You can use it [this way](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ShapeBorder-class.html)

[image]

```dart
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Card with circular border',
    textScaleFactor: 1.2,
  ),
),
Card(
  shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Card with Beveled border',
    textScaleFactor: 1.2,
  ),
),
Card(
  shape: StadiumBorder(
  side: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black,
    width: 2.0,
  ),
),
  child: Text(
    'Card with Stadium border',
    textScaleFactor: 1.2,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Using the RoundedRectangleBorder I also able to get a rounded shape to the Card. But an Image inside it - does not cropped by the Card's rounded image shape. How we can do that? Thanks!

Comment: @SantanuKarar You wrap the image in ClipRRect() - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html

Comment: @aziza how to change border color?

Comment: This answer was super useful to understand how to add borders and colors to chip as well!

Comment: after using Roundedrectangle border with circular it only round bottom card side not upper card side

Answer (score 88):

When Card I always use RoundedRectangleBorder.

```
Card(
  color: Colors.grey[900],
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
            title: Text(
            'example',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
            ),
        ),
        ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Remember to add `elevation: 0` to the `Card` widget to remove the default shadow.

Comment: **how can i apply** only a single border to the card , like **only right border**

Answer (score 35):

You can also customize the card theme globally with `ThemeData.cardTheme`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'savvy',
  theme: ThemeData(
    cardTheme: CardTheme(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(8.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // ...
```

Comment: yes this is modular approach. if you have same style card throughout the app.

Comment: that should be the recommended way!

Answer (score 18):

An Alternative Solution to the above

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ...
)
```

You can use BorderRadius.only() to customize the corners you wish to manage.

Answer (score 12):

A Better way to customise Card Radius ( Also other options ) is to set theme for Card globally. So that you can use same style for Card througout the entire app. You can use this method for many other widget also.

For Card Theme you can use `ThemeData.cardTheme`

```
MaterialApp(
 title: 'MySampleApp',
 theme: ThemeData(
   cardTheme: CardTheme(
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(16.0),
       ),
     ),
   ),
// ............
// ............
```

Comment: U can also use the short-hand `BorderRadius.circular(8)` instead of `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can shape like this in card custom circle with icons

```
Card(
  elevation: 20,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
  ),
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.list,
    size: 92,
  ),
)
```