# How to create an outlined filter chip in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, chips

I'm trying to create an outlined filter chip in Flutter.

I can create a standard filter chip using the following code but I can't see a way to access the outlined version as shown in the image.

Is there a way to modify the standard chip to give the outline version?

```
FilterChip(
   label: Text("text"), 
   onSelected: (bool value) {print("selected");},
),
```

[image: Material Design Filter Chips]

Comment: [Background](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FilterChip/backgroundColor.html)

Comment: Also [ShapeBorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ShapeBorder-class.html)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have it working now. Here is the code:

```
FilterChip(
    label: Text("text"), 
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide()),
    onSelected: (bool value) {print("selected");},
),
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756745/custom-card-shape-flutter-sdk) also helped me discover the StadiumBorder.

Comment: A color that looks nice to me `BorderSide(color: Colors.black12)`.